# Adverb's position

Tags: adverbs

1. The publication will *be* **complimentarily** distributed
2. The publication will **complimentarily** *be* distributed

**1st query: is **Complimentarily** is a right adverb?
**2nd query: will **Complimentarily** be placed in between 'will' and 'be' or after 'will be'?

Comment: I know proof-reading is off-limits, but both sound a bit clumsy to me; I'd suggest "The complimentary publication will be distributed".

Comment: ... or 'The publication will be distributed free of charge'. 'Complimentarily' (1) is so unwieldy that it is rarely used at all, (2) here would modify the verb phrase 'will be distributed'; 'free of charge' for some reason attaches to both the publication and the distribution.

Answer (score 0):

"The publication will complimentarily BE distributed" is an awkward construction and therefore to be avoided.

Your first sentence "The publication will be complimentarily distributed" is grammatically correct and 'complimentarily' is quite OK as adverb.

You can also consider writing it as "The publication will be distributed complimentarily," especially if it is in the context of South Asia (Indian subcontinent) where 'complimentarily' is routinely used as another word for 'free of cost.'

Comment: Members please note that certain terms like 'complimentarily distributed' are routinely used in South Asia although some such constructions may appear unusual to native speakers of English. Similarly we have terms like 'alliance'  (marriage proposal),  'tumbler' (in South India, a steel glass for drinking coffee or water) 'homely mess' (small lunch-house serving simple food) and 'best outgoing student' (top scoring scholar of the high-school-leaving class of the year) - pl. compare with the meaning of alliance, tumbler, homely and outgoing as commonly understood by native speakers of English.